# How to make scrollable and zoomable custom map on Apple Watch?

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos

ViewRanger has a custom map [which can be zoomed and scrolled](https://youtu.be/l0RPIevpaPg?t=34) on the Apple Watch. I didn't find any way to add extra layers to `WKMapView`. The emphasis is on "custom", so I want to have a topological map with my own tile /vector source. How can I create something similar?

Comment: may it helps: https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/build-apple-watch-app-watchkit-tutorial/

Comment: Did someone answered to this question? I was able to reproduce what ViewRanger is doing, basically you can use the static png from the tile server and render it as a texture in a SpriteKit  view. But this is not vectorial. WorkOutDoors app has a pure vectorial map and it is fantastic, but I do not understand how it is done.

Comment: @Georg: I never did it myself, but several apps achieved results using SceneKit and MapKit, like Kartasto and WorkOutDoors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to track gestures separately and call `setRegion(_ coordinateRegion: MKCoordinateRegion)` method on your WKInterfaceMap object to scroll/zoom map.

Comment: My question was not clear enough, sorry. I am looking for a way for adding custom map styles, like topographic maps.